Is it even possible to define "set" non-circularly?
Is it possible to define the notion of "set" in mathematics in a non-circular way? All the informal definitions I have seen basically use a synonym for "set", like "collection" or "aggregate". I am wondering if a good definition of "set" is even possible. Perhaps it is such a basic concept that it must be taken as primitive. But I want to know, what have philosophers, especially philosophers of mathematics, written about this topic?

Correct: it is so basic, that we can hardly imagine something more basic... philosophers consider concept as more basic.

set has more than one meaning. In set-theoretic foundations, it is the basic primitive object with no definition; in other foundations, it may be defined from more basic objects like types.

See What is the definition of set

A set is "simply" a collection of objects. If you find that off in some way, would you give your nod of approval to a group of objects? To call a set a collection isn't circular; it's a valid type of definition known as synonymous definition. If you understand what a collection is then you automatically grok what a set is. You would need to qualify the word "set" if you're in the domain of mathematics with the word "mathematical". Once you become aware of the context you can drop "mathematical" and just write/say "set". Cogito ... cogito ... cogito ...

If you use first-order logic, you formalize a language for expressing properties of things, and you have rules for making deductions from those propositions. Let's call a proposition a formula. Let's call multiple formulae put together a description.
The description is what we use to describe a type of thing. Let's not use the forbidden S-word in the title of your question. Let's try to define something through its properties.
This thing can be chiefly defined by its relation to other such things. Specifically, we want to describe how it can be "inside" other things. We can use a relation symbol like R to represent "being inside", so that xRy means "x is inside y".
We can add more propositions to our description. I'll just use the word "in", instead of the relation symbol R. For example, if we say:

There exists x, y, and z, such that:
x in y
x not in x
y in z

This description might describe what we imagine to be the properties of say, three distinct things, where the first is inside the second, and the second inside the third. But based on the above propositions, it might not work as perfectly as we thought. For example, does the above description strictly exclude the possibility that y is inside y? Do we want that, or do we not?
So, we can keep exploring better descriptions, and notice what kinds of things they seem to describe. For example, I can say:

There are some things. For all x amongst such things, x is not in x.

You can keep adding propositions to your description, to observe what kinds of things it seems to describe. If you realize that the description isn't precise enough, add more propositions to try to hone in on what you want to describe with a perfect description. If you realize that your description has some propositions that are actually wrong, and they do not describe the thing you want to describe perfectly, then get rid of those propositions, or modify them.

It is possible to define a universe of sets suitable for set theory without defining the members of the universe or establishing it as a collection. The most-attended approach is ETCS, the Elementary Theory of the Category of Sets. In this approach, the fundamental objects are functions, and sets are merely the sources and targets of functions. Nonetheless, ETCS + Replacement is bi-interpretable with ZFC.

Can't say for sure, non liquet, but there are many ways of defining words. What we have in the case of what folks in the comments have referred to as primitives are the issues of infinite regress OR circularity in re definition. This is problematic insofar as we're trying to provide an intensional definition, wherein we list out features in the definiens that picks out those and only those objects that the definiendum is supposed to refer to.
My hunch is we can use an ostensive definition (the way of pointing) for sets. If the idea is primitive, shouldn't the method of defining be as/more "primitive"? We could e.g. write down a few of what we consider sets and then point to them and say/write "sets".

Computer science answer
There are no sets natively in CS/programming. Just lists.
Note on terminology: By list I mean more the math notion of sequence rather than more specific CS engineering notions like linked-list. These latter can be considered typical implementations of the former.
Note on Notation: We represent sets like {1,2,3} and lists like [1,2,3].

The most common name under which all programmers know of list is as array. But more modern languages offer better versions of lists.
Define Sets from Lists — informal
Sets are just lists with order ignored.
More precisely, sets are lists with order and repetition ignored.
If we  keep repetition but drop order we get multisets (also called bags).
Define Sets from Lists — formal
A set is an equivalence class of lists.
The equivalence relation is defined by saying lists x and y are related if they differ at most in order and repetition counts.
eg. The lists [1,2,3], [3,1,2], [1,1,2,2,2,3] are all equivalent under this relation although they are not equal and the equivalence class is conventionally written as {1,2,3}.
Question of Equality
A subtle point to note:  For the equivalence relation on lists to be well defined, equality on the list elements needs to be well defined.  This can be a significant issue for complex types, notably functions, where it devolves into the halting problem!
More Philosophical Answer
We can say {1,2,3} and {2,1,3} and {1,2,2,3,3,3} are the same set.
But note that what we see — call it (list of) text or characters or pictographs — are different!
So in some deep way, order is unelidable.
Once that is accepted, the status of 'higher sets' like ℝ are suspect. We really can only 'reach' the computable reals.

Good answer. I was wondering ... whether the fact that math is an axiomatic system means anything in this context? There are multiple ways of crafting a definition. My suggestion that we should employ the ancient, hence first, method of defining objects viz. pointing (ostensively) didn't go down well with most folks here.

@Hudjefa If we take math as going back to Pythagoras, it is 2½ thousand years old. Axiomatics is a fad of the last  century.  I think it is important to accord passing fads and fancies with the right weight. It is true Euclid introduced the axiomatic method. But it was v v different from the arbitrary game playing that took over late 19th century. The original sense of Euclid's axiom is something that is good to take as true. Note the Platonic overtones...

Gracias for the history lesson, informative and eye-opening. Your answer is a superb synopsis of where we stand with regard to the topic. Don't know why you were given the thumbs down (twice). When I alluded to the axiomatic nature of math, I meant to inquire whether this fact has consequences for definitions. I'm also surprised that a known, although likely much disparaged, method of definition (ostensive) is not being considered here.

@Hudjefa ostensive defs means demonstrating defs. The trouble with  such defs for sets is acute. What exactly are you demonstrating when you demonstrate that there is no 1-to-1 correspondence between ℕ and  ℝ? For the classic set theorist it proves that ℕ and  ℝ are not equipotent. For the intuitionist it proves no no such thing though he doesn't dispute Cantors proof because he questions whether ℝ is a well defined set at all!

This is the whole problem with classic set theory. What I call "locutionism" which they pretentiously call Platonism. Just because I can make a sentencial parseable phrase like Set of all sets that are not elements of themselves that is ostensibly parseable doesn't immediately lead to the fact that the phrase means/denotes anything sensible. See Chomsky sentences
